# Exact match formula is not matching correctly in excel, seems to be selecting first match

Tags: excel, string-matching, exact-match

I'm stumped. I have a list of Names called "Exercise_Database".

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Step 6 CLOSE HANDSTAND PUSHUPS Beginner 1 set of 5 reps | CLOSE HANDSTAND PUSHUPS |
| 2 | Step 7 UNEVEN HANDSTAND PUSHUPS Beginner 1 set of 5 reps (L/R) | HANDSTAND PUSHUPS |
| 3 | Step 8 1/2 ONE-ARM HANDSTAND PUSHUPS Beginner 1 set of 4 reps (L/R) | 1/2 ONE-ARM HANDSTAND PUSHUPS |
| 4 | Step 9 LEVER HANDSTAND PUSHUPS Beginner 1 set of 3 reps (L/R) | HANDSTAND PUSHUPS |
| 5 | Step 10 ONE-ARM HANDSTAND PUSHUPS Beginner 1 set of 1 reps (L/R) | HANDSTAND PUSHUPS |

```
IF(ISBLANK(A1),"",IFERROR(INDEX(EXERCISE_DATABASE,MATCH(1,COUNTIF(A1,"*"&EXERCISE_DATABASE&"*"),0),1),"No Match"))
```

I don't understand why the formula is giving me the exact match I'm requesting. Here's the Exercise List...

Exercise Database

```
1/2 ONE-ARM HANDSTAND PUSHUPS
1/2 ONE-ARM PULLUPS
1/2 ONE-ARM PUSHUPS
1/2 ONE-LEG SQUATS
ANGLED BRIDGES
ASSISTED ONE-ARM PULLUPS
ASSISTED ONE-LEG SQUATS
CLOSE HANDSTAND PUSHUPS
CLOSE PULLUPS
CLOSE PUSHUPS
CLOSE SQUATS
CLOSING BRIDGES
CROW STANDS
FLAT BENT LEG RAISES
FLAT FROG RAISES
FLAT KNEE RAISES
FLAT STRAIGHT LEG RAISES
FULL BRIDGES
FULL PULLUPS
FULL PUSHUPS
FULL SQUATS
HALF BRIDGES
HALF HANDSTAND PUSHUPS
HALF PULLUPS
HALF PUSHUPS
HALF SQUATS
HANDSTAND PUSHUPS
HANGING BENT LEG RAISES
HANGING FROG RAISES
HANGING KNEE RAISES
HANGING STRAIGHT LEG RAISES
HEAD BRIDGES
HORIZONTAL PULLS
INCLINE PUSHUPS
JACKKNIFE PULLS
JACKKNIFE SQUATS
KNEE TUCKS
KNEELING PUSHUPS
LEVER HANDSTAND PUSHUPS
LEVER PUSHUPS
ONE-ARM HANDSTAND PUSHUPS
ONE-ARM PULLUPS
ONE-ARM PUSHUPS
ONE-LEG SQUATS
PARTIAL STRAIGHT LEG RAISES
SHORT BRIDGES
SHOULDERSTAND SQUATS
STAND-TO- STAND BRIDGES
STRAIGHT BRIDGES
SUPPORTED SQUATS
UNEVEN HANDSTAND PUSHUPS
UNEVEN PULLUPS
UNEVEN PUSHUPS
UNEVEN SQUATS
VERTICAL PULLS
WALL HANDSTANDS
WALL HEADSTANDS
WALL PUSHUPS
WALL WALKING BRIDGES (DOWN)
WALL WALKING BRIDGES (UP)
```

Here's a complete image of all the matches being performed...
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MghQr.png)

Comment: order the lookup table by length of string and not alpha.

Comment: Didn't work. I get worse results.

Comment: the sort should be by length descending with the longest on top.

Comment: THANK YOU.  That did it. Is this always true or is it because of the formula I'm using?

Comment: it has to do with how this particular formula works.  You need to test the longest strings first, because it will return the first that resolves to true.

Comment: Thanks again. Scott.